# How to print a ArrayList of String arrays in java which is a value of Map

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to print the content of this attribute:

```
private HashMap<RegionVersObj,  ArrayList<String[]>> region;
```

I have done this with the below code.
Inside the `toString(`) method I am iterating with the Map Entry.
I have created a `StringBuffer` object and appending the content in it.

```
 public String toString() {     
        StringBuffer regionToPrint = new StringBuffer();
          for (Map.Entry<RegionVersObj,  ArrayList<String[]>> entry : region.entrySet())
            {
              regionToPrint.append(entry.getKey().toString());
              regionToPrint.append("=[");
              for(String[] s:entry.getValue()){
                  regionToPrint.append("[");
                  for(String s1:s){
                      regionToPrint.append(s1);
                      regionToPrint.append(",");
                  }
                  regionToPrint.append("],");
              }
        }

        return "region=" + regionToPrint.toString();
    }
```

This is the way I am trying to solving this. But I want to know is there any better way in which I can solve this?

Comment: Try reading about `streams` if you are using `java8`.

Comment: You can use java.util.Arrays.toString(strArr)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the JAVA 1.8. Since it has the more in build functions. Example we can make the `String[]` array into comma separated values using `String.join()`

```
 region.forEach((k,v)->{
              regionToPrint.append(k.toString());
              regionToPrint.append("=[");
              for(String[] s:v){
                  regionToPrint.append("[");
                  regionToPrint.append(String.join(",", s));
                  regionToPrint.append("],");
              }
              regionToPrint.append("],");
        });
```